# Is the Friedman Test Suitable For an Analysis of Pre/Post-Intervention Choices From Survey Data?

Tags: nonparametric, survey

We sent out a survey to find if educational material about a type of surgery would potentially influence the decision of subjects. Prior to giving them this educational material we asked them demographic questions (e.g. sex, job, etc.), several questions on a 5 point scale to assess their priorities (e.g. "How important is cosmesis?"). After receiving this educational material we then asked them which type of surgery they potentially would be interested in.

For this analysis, I would like to see if

1. the pre and post-educational material preferences changed
2. if demographic information (e.g. age, education, sex) has an influence on choice after receiving the educational material
3. if the pre-educational material priorities are associated with change in choice after receiving

This survey was given to a random group of medical professionals, and I am assuming that the distribution of the data collected from this population is non-normal.

This makes me think that I need to perform non-parametric tests, but I am having difficulty in figuring out which test would be best. So far I think I may have to perform a Friedman Test since I want to do a pre/post comparison between the same group. However I would appreciate if anyone could clarify the matter for me. Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

There are pairs of “pretreatment” and “posttreatment” observations, two observations on each of n subjects (blocks, patients, etc.). This null hypothesis of WILCOXON test asserts that each of the distributions (not necessarily the same) for the differences (posttreatment minus pretreatment observations) is symmetrically distributed about 0, corresponding to no shift in location due to the treatment.

Comment: That should be WIlcoxon signed-rank test.  Better is the rank difference test discussed [here](https://hbiostat.org/bbr/nonpar).